# WordPress 5.0 Update Issue

Tags: wordpress

I was doing a routine update procedure on a WordPress website and then I just simply updated the WordPress website and everything started to fell, well all the links are now not loading from the domain itself but instead form a weird domain that seems to be like a CDN but it's actually nothing I have attached console logs so anyone can help me as the styles and all the CSS files are not loading that is making everything worse.

[image: Console]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wp.com domain is owned by Automattic, a popular Wordpress commercial service provider (Wordpress.com, WooCommerce, WooThemes, and others). Are you using their plugin Jetpack ? I have been reading forum threads lately of people having similar issues and they were all using the Jetpack plugin with its CDN option enabled.

There is a setting to disable the CDN in Jetpack that may fix this issue. However, some are not able to resolve the issue this way. In this case, I've seen Automattic staff members encouraging people to [file a support ticket](https://jetpack.com/support/) for one-on-one support.

Answer (score 1):

You are using jetpack plugin

disable CDN option

or you can paste the CSS into Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS to provide a temporary fix.